# SQL query by if(!empty($_GET for Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to do a query for a wordpress plugin but I can't figure it out by mayself. I want to limit post by category ids and if not any category was given, than show all post. My sql is:

```
$sql = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->posts.post_content, $wpdb->posts.post_excerpt, $wpdb->posts.post_name
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
        ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
        ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'".
        if(!empty($_GET["category"])) {
        "AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".htmlspecialchars($_GET["category"])."'".
        }
        "ORDER BY post_date DESC";
```

As you can understand, I'm trying to get category id by url like **&category=12** but thats giving me a blank page (no errors or like) could you guys help me with that?

Comment: Blank pages use to mean syntax error. Have you ever see PHP error log?

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Wordpress already has enough holes in it. Don't introduce more.

Comment: @devon: htmlspecialchars is utterly **USELESS** to injection attacks.

Comment: @devon: cf my update (bottom of my answer) WP does support prepared statements (not sure how it's implemented, but I'd use `$wpdb->prepare` anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put an if in the middle of a string.  You can use the concatenating assignment operator to add to the `$sql` variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->posts.post_content, $wpdb->posts.post_excerpt, $wpdb->posts.post_name
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
        ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
        ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'";

if(!empty($_GET["category"])) {
    $sql .= " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".htmlspecialchars($_GET["category"], ENT_QUOTES)."'";
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY post_date DESC";
```

I also added the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to htmlspecialchars() to translate single quotes into `&#039;`.  This would add protection from injections, not allowing people to put a single quote in and inject their own query.

**Prepared Statements**

Look at Elias' answer on using prepared statements with Wordpress.  Prepared statements are much safer than relying on any in place function to validate input.

Comment: Don't forget to add spaces when concatenating like `$sql .= ' ORDER BY...';` it never hurts. Quite the opposite: it avoids potential SQL syntax errors like `$sql = 'SELECT field, field2'; /* some code */ $sql .= 'FROM tbl';` which might yield `SELECT field, field2FROM tbl`

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** concatenate **statements** into ***expressions***. You can only concatenate *expressions*, so you'll have to use a ternary:

```
"AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'".
(!empty($_GET['category']) ? 
    "AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '". htmlspecialchars($_GET["category"]) . "'" : '')
. "rest of query";
```

But really, this isn't the way to query the DB (it's massively unsafe... honestly) *and* it's messy, and hellish to maintain, *and* you're not checking `isset` on the `$_GET` params.

Basically, everything that can (and likely should) contain a semi-colon, is a statement:

```
$foo = "bar";//statement
```

This simple assignment statement falls consists of several *expressions*, of which `"bar"` is one. This statement also happens to be an expression, but that's not the point. The point is that:

```
if ($condition)
{
    //STATEMENT(S)
}
```

is ***not*** an expression, so it can't be incorporated into a single statement (like in your case, an the assignmend of  a query string to a variable called `$sql`).

***Warning***

Your query is, as others have pointed out, [vulnerable to injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). WP allows you to use [prepared statements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), and you really should do so:

```
$id = $_POST['some_value'];//check isset first, of course
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = %d',
        $id
    )
);
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch but I didn't realize you could use ternary inside a string.  Useful.

Comment: @Devon: Of course you can, why else would the ternary operator exist, other than to allow for branching (`if`'s and `else`'s) in an expression. Be that as it may: the PHP ternary is quite broken, and in this case, the OP should be looking into alternative ways of tackling the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all affords. @Devon's code worked very well.
By the way, I'm editing XML Export script for Wordpress's Woocommerce plugin.

Original plugin link is:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/beslist-xml-feed-voor-woocommerce/

And you can download edited version of this plugin here:
https://github.com/eXspet/beslist-xml-edited

What I've changed:

- You can get XML feeds by category (with your helps, obviously)
- You can see gallery images for woocommerce product in XML file.
- You can see short & full description for every products
- You can show your default currency by changing `<kur>USD</kur>`
- You can view all XML feeds via wordpress admin panel.

I'm not a coder, so I don't know much about security, If you notice any security open in this plugin, please let me know. Thanks everyone, again.

Comment: You might want to post some of your code on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). That's the place to turn to if you're unsure about any of your code. If your code works, you just submit it there to get some pointers on how to improve it (like your `beslist_feeds_page_settings` function => functions shouldn't `echo` (they `return`), and avoid using `global` => use arguments instead, and loose the closing `?>` tag, to conform to [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) coding standards (cf 2.2)